# SSIS datetime conversion issue between excel and sql

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, datetime, ssis

if I bang my head on my desk 1 more time I might be gone forever.

Source: Excel

Data: 2012-10-05T11:14:00

Conversion:

2012-10-05T11:14:00 in Excel to string [DT_STR]

Destination: SQL

Column Data Type: datetime

I keep getting the following errors:

[PostBindInspectionsBucket [20]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

[PostBindInspectionsBucket [20]] Error: There was an error with input column "Copy of RequestTimestamp" (112) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (33). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

[PostBindInspectionsBucket [20]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (33)" failed because error code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (33)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "PostBindInspectionsBucket" (20) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (33). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

What am I doing wrong? the format that's coming from Excel is a valid datetime format.

I created a table with a column of type "datetime" and then I pasted in it "2012-10-05T11:14:00" and it worked fine.

I also ran a

```
SELECT ISDATE('2012-10-05T11:14:00')
```

and it's returning 1, which means it's a valid datetime in SQL.

Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: What data type does it think the column in Excel is? What if you you specifically format it as GENERAL or TEXT in Excel? I'm suspicious that Excel formatting is hiding the real underlying value in Excel. Where are you seeing this source date? In Excel or in a data browser in SSIS? What happens if you save your Excel as CSV, inspect it to verify that this is indeed the format of the data, and import it? You may be able to tell I do not trust Excel.

Comment: Also import it into a VARCHAR rather than DATETIME field to again inspect the true nature of the data. Also I have only ever used a date format _without_ the T designator (a space instead) when inserting into tables.

Comment: @ElectricLlama  Excel formatting is almost always hiding/masking a real underlying value, in particular with dates or values which Excel can interpret as dates.

Comment: Your data from Excel is coming in as DT_WSTR (right click on the line from the source to the next component and check properties). You have a conversion from DT_WSTR to DT_STR to datetime? What data type are you attempting to cast to (DT_?)? Is this error from a Data Conversion or is it from the destination?

Comment: @billinkc well spotted - didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was the "T".

I removed the T from the string it went through.