# Getting DataType error in SSIS - Package is failing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have two packages that I built in SSIS. This package goes out to a file path, pulls in two excel files, and loads them to two tables in SQL Server db. One of the packages runs fine and loads its respective table. However, the other excel/csv file contains two date columns and the package is failing because the SQL Server table that it needs to load to has two DateTime columns. The error I am getting is:

-There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[CustDate] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].

I have tried to cast the datetime column to Date in the SQL table, and it still doesn't work and throws the same error. I have added a data conversion task in SSIS to try and convert the two date fields to multiple datatypes, and I still get an error. Can someone please tell me what datatype I should convert these two fields in the SSIS package where it would work? The first package runs fine because it doesn't contain any date fields in the excel file or the table it loads to.

So far, I have tried to convert these two date fields to: string[DT_STR], Unicode string[DT_WSTR], date[DT_DATE] and none of them work. Can anyone offer up any suggestions? Thank you!

So far, I have tried to convert these two date fields to: string[DT_STR], Unicode string[DT_WSTR], date[DT_DATE] and none of them work. Can anyone offer up any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: There will be more errors than that from SSIS. What other warnings/errors are you getting here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS datetime conversion issue between excel and sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799270/ssis-datetime-conversion-issue-between-excel-and-sql)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what your date looks like? It seems that you can load it successfully to your table. That means it's definitely an issue with the format of your date field, which causes it to be non-convertible. If you have any letters in the field consider removing those, as well as applying LTRIM(RTRIM(Date))

Comment: Is the second package reading in Excel (.xlsx) files, or CSV files? CSV files have no data types - everything is stored as raw string values. Likely the dates in your CSV files are in a different format than what your SQL Server's [`DATEFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is set to. When serializing dates to CSV files you should aim for ISO 8601 date format which is unambiguous and can be read in regardless of SQL Server's `DATEFORMAT` setting, e.g.: `"Foo","2018-12-31","Bar"`

Answer (score 0):

Made the following 2 changes. It will give you answer.

1) Select your excel file connection and add IMEX=1 to the end of the connection under properties. So your connection string will now look like

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\SSIS\Test.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";

2) Use the following expression in the derived column transformation

ISNULL([CustDate]) ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (LEN(TRIM([CustDate])) == 0 ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)((DT_DBDATE)TRIM([CustDate])))